# Visa requirements for Sri Lankan passport holder with a 3-year temporary residence permit in Romania

Tags: visas, sri-lankan-citizens

I am an international student living in Romania. I hold a Sri Lankan passport and I have a residence permit in Romania for 3 years. I want to know what countries I can travel to without visa, or on arrival visa.

Thank you.

Comment: There are several hundred "countries" in the world (definitions vary), and entry to most (but not all) depends on one's country of citizenship  and not on one's country of residence. Because of the great number of countries, I voted to close for "Needs more focus."

Comment: Romania is about to join the Schengen area, but that has not come into effect yet. So you would have to specify when you travel. And as pointed out by David, you probably mean countries in Europe but you need to say so.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica your residence status of another Schengen country is actually very relevant to your visa requirement so I don’t think this deserves to be closed

Comment: @deed02392 For the reason you state, residence status in another Schengen country may well be relevant for the OP's visa application, but it remains true that for the majority of visa applications it is not relevant: there are more non-Schengen-resident applicants than Schengen-resident applicants. Non-Schengen resdients will read this question and the comments too.